# Dynamically Load items(Images) in list view on user scroll in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image, listview

I'm using a list view control that is attached to an image list to display thumbnails of images in the list view on a form.I'm adding images from a folder to the image list by using a loop and the following code
`ImageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile("c:\\windows\\img.bmp"))`;

But if there are lots of images a out of memory exception is thrown(even after disposing).I want to load the images to list view which are currently visible to the user,ie:loading the images dynamically on user scroll.If 5 images are in user view i want to load only 5 images,if the user scrolls i want to get the index of the images which should be currently visible to user and load those images only.

Please help me out on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I had very good experiences with [ImageListView](http://code.google.com/p/imagelistview/), both in terms of technology (performance) and author's reply (quality and speed).

I use it as a replacement for `ListView` whenever I need visual image lists.

Comment: Thanks.It looks great ,let me try it.

Comment: I added image list view reference to the ToolBox,Added a Control in the form.But when im using Imagelistview1.Items.Add(myitem)i get an Invalid Reference error Manina.Windows.Forms Please Help

Answer (score 0):

My very naive approach would be to extend the `ImageList` class, add a collection of file locations and override the image getter to load the file when first requested (ie, a cache miss).

Otherwise, I expect you should be looking at handling the `ListView` events for scrolling and/or rendering list items. (I assume they exists, haven't dealt with UI for a while)